# Re-tag [PPC] to PowerPC?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[ppc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ppc) is apparently supposed to be a synonym for [powerpc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerpc), according to the [ppc tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ppc/info). The tag appears to be used correctly in most cases, although a few cases mistake it for [pay-per-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pay-per-click).

I don't think this tag is meaningful by itself. Overall we should avoid TLA:s, because they are confusing and hard to understand.

Most questions using [ppc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ppc) should simply be re-tagged to [powerpc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerpc) and a few of them to [pay-per-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pay-per-click).

Comment: Possibly a few Pocket PC questions in there too. That was my first thought when I saw PPC at least.